# 'fsutil' is not recognized as an internal or external command in Batch Script

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

Here's my script which basically creates a file and converts it to a sparse file

**SparseFileCreator.bat**

```
@echo off
echo ************************
echo * SPARSE FILE CREATION *
echo ************************
set /p path=Enter the Path :
set /p fname=Enter the Filename :
set /p fsize=Enter the filesize (in Mb) :
set /a sizeinbytes=fsize*1024*1024
fsutil file createnew %path%\%fname% %sizeinbytes%
fsutil sparse setflag %path%\%fname% 
fsutil sparse setflag %path%\%fname% 0 %sizeinbytes%
pause
```

When I run this Batch Script I get the following error, but I'm able to launch fsutil.exe from other cmd windows except the one which I used to run the batch script. Any Ideas why this is happening?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overwritting the `%path%` environment variable, used to locate executable files. Change the variable name.

Comment: Thanks :) Such an amateur mistake I totally overlooked that part !