# 'fsutil' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe, fsutil

Hi im having an issue with a batch file. im trying to run fsutil and take the user entry of size, name, and location and pass that to cmd to create files...i have copied a piece of code that was on this site but cannot figure out what is wrong ..any help would be much appreciated

```
    @echo off
echo ************************
echo * SPARSE FILE CREATION *
echo ************************
set /p path=Enter the Path :
set /p fname=Enter the Filename :
set /p fsize=Enter the filesize (in Mb) :
set /a sizeinbytes=fsize*1024*1024
fsutil file createnew %path%\%fname% %sizeinbytes%
fsutil sparse setflag %path%\%fname% 
fsutil sparse setflag %path%\%fname% 0 %sizeinbytes%
pause
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['fsutil' is not recognized as an internal or external command in Batch Script](https://superuser.com/questions/887663/fsutil-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-in-batch-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I'm trying to run fsutil

> 'fsutil' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Your batch file is broken because you are overriding the [path](http://ss64.com/nt/path.html) environment variable:

> set /p path=Enter the Path :

Use another name for this variable. I like to prefix all my batch variable with `_` to avoid this problem.

Corrected batch file:

```
@echo off
echo ************************
echo * SPARSE FILE CREATION *
echo ************************
set /p _path=Enter the Path :
set /p fname=Enter the Filename :
set /p fsize=Enter the filesize (in Mb) :
set /a sizeinbytes=fsize*1024*1024
fsutil file createnew %_path%\%fname% %sizeinbytes%
fsutil sparse setflag %_path%\%fname% 
fsutil sparse setflag %_path%\%fname% 0 %sizeinbytes%
pause
```

---

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [environment variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) - Environment variables are mainly used within batch files, they can be created, modified and deleted for a session using the SET command.
- [path](http://ss64.com/nt/path.html) - Display or set a search path for executable files.
- [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

Comment: thanks so simple yet i didnt notice the error in my ways